# R: Debugging and tracing messages?

Tags: r, debugging, traceback

Whereas `options(warn=2)` will prompt an error and hence enable debugging, I'm struggling with doing the same for messages.

For example, somewhere in my codebase, an unknown function seems to use `jsonlite`-package, which triggers the [following message](https://rdrr.io/cran/jsonlite/src/R/warn_keep_vec_names.R).

So my question is: **Is there a convenient way to trace back the origins of messages**?

Note: Using `browser()` doesn't seem to help, since messages are not shown in browser-mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wrap your code in a call to `withCallingHandlers` to turn messages into errors:

```
withCallingHandlers(
  message("example message"),
  message = function(m) stop(m)
)
#Error in message("example message") : example message
```